# Ubuntu 20.04 Wifi disapears after kernel update

Tags: wireless, updates, windows, troubleshooting

I have a recurrent issue with Ubuntu 20.04, which works fine otherwise. Every now and then, general updating triggers a kernel update. After rebooting, and not before, my Wifi disappears and I cannot reconnect the Wifi.

The last occurrence of the problem was when upgrading to
Ubuntu with Linux 5.13.0-21-generic

My only solution so far is to reboot with an older kernel, now
Ubuntu with Linux 5.11.0-40-generic

and things suddenly go back to normal with available wifi and internet connection. Looking here and there on various forums, I also add that I have a Windows 7 ârtition, which may interfere with the process.

Results of `lshw -C network` :

```
WARNING: you should run this program as super-user. 

*-network description: Wireless interface 
product: AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) 
vendor: Qualcomm Atheros 
physical id: 0 
bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0 
logical name: wlp3s0
```

Comment: How is Unix related? Probably a kernel upgrade? What is the wireless adapter? Did you install any drivers and how?

Comment: Kernel update is the most likely the key here. For everyhtong else leo@leo-G53SX:~$ lshw -C network
WARNING: you should run this program as super-user.
  *-network                 
       description: Wireless interface
       product: AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express)
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: wlp3s0

Comment: Unix no longer exists as something that can be updated. What currently remains is UNIX, a trademarked certification program managed by The Open Group (macOS, for example, is UNIX certified). When you use certain terms in your question, many of us become cornfused about what the actual question is. Additionally, there is likely not enough information to answer your question. Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1377021/edit) your question to include the specific kernel version numbers.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion but, by every stretch of imagination, I am the most confused here.

Comment: Looking here and there on various forums, I also add that I have a Windows 7 partition, which may interfere with the process.

Comment: Quite often with Ubuntu, and as in life, a fresh start solves most troubles. So a clean re-install it was, with Windows 7 removed once and for all, and everything is back to normal. Just one or two workdays gone, but well...